# One time record insertion then update many times

Tags: c#

I have a form where a user can insert, view and update data. Data insertion is done only once, then updates can be done many times. By default, the user will be able to view the data if it exists in the database.

I tried this but it doesn't insert into database. Then suppose a data exists in database and when the user wants to update the record, it throws an error - DataReader is open.

```
   private void display_Emp()
    {
        try
        {
            using (sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                sqlCon.Open(); 

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Employee", sqlCon);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet("Employee");
                da.Fill(ds, "Employee");
                int x = 0;
                for (x = 0; x < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; x++)
                {
                    txtID.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[x][1].ToString();
                    txtEmpName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[x][2].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exx) {
            MessageBox.Show(exx.Message);
        }
        finally {
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
    }

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try 
    {
        using (sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employee", sqlCon);

            read = com.ExecuteReader(); 

            while (read.Read())
            {                     
                if (read.HasRows) 
                {
                    SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Employee SET EmpID = '" + txtID.Text + "' , EmpName = '" + txtEmpName.Text + "', sqlCon);
                    update.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Employee details updated!", "Employee", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employee(EmpID, EmpName) VALUES ('" + txtID.Text + "','" + txtEmpName.Text + "')", sqlCon);
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Employee details saved!", "Employee", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally 
    {
        read.Close();
        sqlCon.Close();
    }                   
}
```

**EDIT:**

Table:- Deepz (ID int PK, Goodname varchar(50) )

```
DECLARE @ID int 
DECLARE @Goodname varchar(50) 

    MERGE Deepz t
    USING (SELECT @ID[ID], @Goodname[Goodname]) s 
        ON (t.ID = s.ID)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE
        SET t.Goodname = @Goodname
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (ID, Goodname)
        VALUES (@ID, @Goodname);
```

Errors:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 't'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".
```

Comment: using same connection for `datareader` and `ExecuteNonQuery` doesn't work ! `datareader` holds the connection exclusively as it's connection-oriented approach

Comment: **WARNING**:  Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.  Please use [SQL Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

Comment: Where are you declaring `read`?

Comment: I declared it at the top, right after public partial class EmployeeForm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your save functionality to:

- If  you're on SQL Server 2008 or later, use [SQL Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement to insert or update depending on whether record exists or not

```
    DECLARE @nameField    VarChar(50) = 'some data'

    MERGE dbo.MyTable t
    USING (SELECT @nameField [field]) s
        ON t.myData = s.field
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE
        SET t.myData = @nameField
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (myData)
        VALUES (@nameField);
```

- If  you are on SQL Server 2005 or earlier, you will need to use something like below, but you may have a race condition (but imho will still be better than your original design, which has the potential for a race condition as well) so depending on your environment you may need to play around with locks, etc

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Deepz WHERE [ID] = @ID)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Deepz
        SET Goodname = @Goodname
        WHERE [ID] = @ID
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT Deepz (ID, Goodname)
        VALUES (@ID, @Goodname);
    END
```

- Use sql params instead of building the statement by concatenation, will save you from [SQL injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) attacks

```
    UPDATE Employee SET EmpID = @id, EmpName = @name
```

then

```
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(...);
    // note below is a bit simplified, in reality you should do int.TryParse
    comm.Parameters.Add(@id, SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(txtID.Text);
```

Comment: @deepz you should only need one SqlCommand, and the command itself will be the merge statement like the example I provided in the answer.  The key is base the merge `USING ... ON ...` section on your table's unique constraint (what helps you differentiate one record from another), then you just need to pass the values to your param, and run one SqlCommand that will do insert/update based on the existence or not

Comment: I've first tried the merge statement in Sql Server 2005, to test whether or not it's working. I got some errors. Please see my EDIT.

Comment: @deepz see the updated answer, I didn't realize you were using pre SQL Server 2008, the **Merge** statement was introduced in SQL Server 2008, so you will have to revert to an old if exists/else, but this can still be done in one single SQL command, simplified and more efficient than your original approach, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark but, try this:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try 
   {
      using (sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString))
      {
         sqlCon.Open();
         SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employee", sqlCon);
         com.Parameters.AddWithValue(@empID, SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(txtID.Text);  // Add this line
         com.Parameters.AddWithValue(@empName, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmpName.Text; // Add this line too
         SqlDataReader read = new SqlDataReader();  // You also need to 'new' up your SqlDataReader.
         read = com.ExecuteReader(); 

         while (read.Read())
         {                     
            if (read.HasRows) 
            {
            SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Employee SET EmpID = @empID, EmpName = @empName", sqlCon);
            update.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Employee details updated!", "Employee", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
             }

             else
             {
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employee(EmpID, EmpName) VALUES (@empID, @empName)", sqlCon);
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Employee details saved!", "Employee", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
             }
         }
    }

    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    finally 
    {
        read.Close();
        sqlCon.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but the answer to my real question is still pending.

Answer (score 0):

From the examples i'm looking at the "If" condition and "While" condition look like they are inverted.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

You check to see if there are rows first and then iterate over them